# How to curl Publisher url in wso2 apim?

Tags: curl, wso2-api-manager, wso2, publisher

I have run the wso2 apim 3.2.0 server, there is no error in logs but when I am trying to open the publisher URL from chrome through bastion host server proxy, the page is not showing up.
To debug from the console, I want some exact URL to curl to check if the publisher page is up and running.
I tried  `curl -k https://localhost:9443/publisher` but it shows some proxy error...

```
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Is there any other way to curl any other URL related to the publisher which indirectly tells me if the publisher page is up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's redirected to the login page. You can use the below.

```
curl -kv https://localhost:9443/publisher/site/pages/login.jag
```